# Swagger configured in Spring Boot shows only methods with POST and GET mapping

Tags: spring, spring-boot, configuration, swagger, swagger-ui

Swagger configured in Spring Boot shows only one method with *POST* mapping and one method with *GET* mapping from every controller. Swagger ignores another methods with *GET* and *POST* mapping and ignores all methods with *PUT* and *DELETE* mappings. My configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("my.project.controllers"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/*"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Dependency in pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My controllers code:

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/users", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public class UserController {

```
@Autowired
private UserService userService;

protected UserService getService() {
    return userService;
}

@RequestMapping(method = GET)
public Page<User> query(@RequestParam Map<String, Object> parameters, Pageable pageable) {
    return getService().query(parameters, pageable);
}

@ResponseStatus(CREATED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<User> create(@RequestBody User entity) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(getService().create(entity));
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:[0-9]+}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<User> update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody User entity) {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(getService().update(id, entity));
}

@RequestMapping("/current")
public ResponseEntity current() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUser());
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:[0-9]+}/enable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void enable(@PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    userService.enable(id);
}

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id:[0-9]+}/disable", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void disable(@PathVariable("id") final long id) {
    userService.disable(id);
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/histories", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<UserHistory> histories() {
    return userService.histories();
}
```

}

May be i need add some more configuration or add something else?

Comment: can you please show some controller code?

Comment: I added controller code. Other controller are the same. Swagger shows only query method and create method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your controller, I think you should add one more star in the path matcher in your swagger config:

`.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/**"))`

e.g /api/users/current would not be matched by the /api/* but by /api/**, and this why you are getting only the base path endpoints documented.

Comment: When I added one more star, application throws an exception:
`org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1`

Dont you know what is this exception?)

Comment: weird. Can you try with a regular expression: `.paths(regex("/api.*"))` or `.paths(PathSelectors.ant("/api**"))`

Comment: I solved it.
Thank you, Zakaria. Your answer is correct. 

This exception appears because in one of my controllers I have parameter "java.util.Map" without any generics. When I add "<String, Object>" to my Map - I solved problem with.

My next task - add authorization, like in example project on swagger.io .